# Cartopy IllegalArgumentException verbose

Tags: python-3.x, cartopy

I'm new to cartopy. When I do a basic plot of data across a Europe domain I get repeated error messages of;

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
Shell is not a LinearRing
```

This behaviour doesn't happen when I I make `Data=np.zeros((721,1440))`. Code below (Anaconda, did clean install, python 3).

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pygrib

File = pygrib.open('GFS_0.25.grb2')

Data = File.select(name='Temperature',level=850)[0].values

Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,1440)
Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,721)


crs = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=0, central_latitude=45.0)
bounds = [(-50, 50, 25., 65)]

ax1 = plt.subplot(111,projection=crs)
ax1.set_extent(*bounds)
ax1.coastlines('50m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.75)
ax1.contourf(Lon,Lat,Data,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Data is at https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApWaJaYUUERKjqEf2ZABOrvf4UpB9g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in cartopy which was fixed in v0.16 released on 21st Feb 2018 (see: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/885). Upgrading will get rid of the warnings.

Comment: I still get `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4` and then
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)` at times (Conda, cartopy                   v0.16.0  build py36hf32a85a_0)

Comment: Update; avoiding the use of `np.linspace(-180,180,720),np.linspace(-90,90,360)` for coordinate data and instead using `np.linspace(-179.99,179.99,720),np.linspace(-89.99,89.99,360)` solves this issue